# Using beef fat for baking

Tags: baking, cookies, fat

I have a large amount of very good quality dry aged beef fat (not suet). I would like to try making cookies using the beef fat in place of the butter. I was thinking of using a simple shortbread-style recipe or something similar (i.e. no other flavourings apart from the fat and sugar), just replacing the butter with rendered beef fat. I am, however, aware that the melting point of beef fat is comparatively low.

Is this possible, and what adjustments should I make, if any?

Comment: Rendered beef fat, referred to as "dripping", is a traditional ingredient in British cooking. If you search for "beef dripping" you will find plenty of resources to help and inform you.

Answer (score 5):

Shortbread dough made with lard is delicious. I have never used beef fat, but both pork fat and goose fat have worked perfectly for me in this setting. I prefer the texture over the texture of shortbread baked with butter. So go ahead and make it, it's very likely that you get very similar results to pork or goose fat.